# CABS(x) function for complex(8)

Tags: fortran

Is there an absolute value function for a complex value in double precision? When I try `CABS()` I get

```
            V(1,j) = R(j,j) + (R(j,j)/cabs(R(j,j)))*complexnorm2(R(j:m,j))
```

> "Error: Type of argument 'a' in call to 'cabs' at (1) should be
>   COMPLEX(4), not COMPLEX(8)"

I have read there's a function called `CDABS()` but I wasnt sure if that was the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason using anything else than `ABS()`. Generics for intrinsic procedures were already present in FORTRAN 77. You can use them for all intrinsic numeric types.

If you want to see the table of available specific functions of the generic `ABS()`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ABS.html , but they are mostly useful only to be passed as actual arguments. You can see that `CDABS()` is a non-standard extension and I do not recommend to use it.

Answer (score 2):

`CABS` is defined by the standard to take an argument of type default complex.  In your implementation this looks like `complex(kind=4)`.  There is no standard function `CDABS`, although your implementation may perhaps offer one: read the appropriate documentation.

Further, there is no standard specific function for the generic function `ABS` which takes a `double complex` argument.  Again, your implementation may offer one called something other than `CDABS`.

That said, the generic function `ABS` takes any integer, real, or complex argument.  Use that.

Comment: Thank you Francescalus, too low level to vote up otherwise i would

Answer (score 0):

COMPLEX*8 and complex(KIND=8) are not the same.
The first one, is 4 byte real and 4 byte imaginary.

The complex(KIND=8) or COMPLEX(KIND=C_DOUBLE) is actually a double precision real and double precision imaginary... So equivalent to COMPLEX*16.

As mentioned ABS() should be fine.

Comment: `complex*8` doesn't appear in the question at all.  But either way `complex*8` doesn't, by Fortran, consist of two 4-byte components: it's a non-standard extension understood in certain ways by compilers.  Equally, `complex(8)` could mean anything/nothing.  `complex*16` if it means anything may be entirely different from `complex(8)` and `complex(c_double)`.

Comment: That is exactly why I posted that @francescalus ... It is easy to find (or stumble across) code that looks like this... And easy to get wrapped around the axle.