# How to compute the magnitude of each complex number in an array?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm attempting to test a program that calculates the discrete Fourier transform of a signal, namely a sine wave. To test it, I need to plot my results. However, the result is an array of size N (currently at 400) and is filled with complex numbers of the form *z = x + iy*. So I know that to test it I need to plot these results, and that to do this I need to plot *|z|*. Here's my program:

```
program DFT
implicit none
integer :: k, N, x, y, j, r, l, istat, p
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
real, allocatable,dimension(:) :: h
complex, allocatable, dimension(:) :: rst
complex, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: W
real(kind=dp) :: pi
p = 2*pi
!open file to write results to
open(unit=100, file="dft.dat", status='replace')

N = 400
!allocate arrays as length N, apart from W (NxN)
allocate(h(N))
allocate(rst(N))
allocate(W(-N/2:N/2,1:N))

pi = 3.14159265359
!loop to create the sample containing array
do k=1,N
  h(k) = sin((2*pi*k)/N)
end do

!loop to fill the product matrix with values
do j = -N/2,N/2
do k = 1, N

    W(j,k) = EXP((2.0_dp*pi*cmplx(0.0_dp,1.0_dp)*j*k)/N)

end do
end do
!use of matmul command to multiply matrices
rst = matmul(W,h)
print *, h, w
write(100,*) rst

end program
```

So my question is how do I take the magnitude of all the individual complex numbers in the array?

Comment: The above program is rather strange in a few ways. Firstly pi is not set a value before you use it. Secondly the majority of the real and complex constants have kind dp, which the majority of the variables are of default kind - I suggest you make them consistent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CABS(x) function for complex(8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221817/cabsx-function-for-complex8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ABS intrinsic function returns the magnitude of a complex number in Fortran. It is an elemental function as well, so for an array of type complex simply ABS( array ) will return a real array with the same kind as the original containing the results you want.